# Proper way to create a Trim type

Tags: typescript

I was reading the typescript 4.5beta blog post, the author implemented a `TrimLeft` utility type to show `Tail-Recursion Elimination on Conditional Types` , so I decided to implement a `Trim` utility type ( for learning purposes), my question is, what would you and how would you have done it differently?

```js
type Trim<T extends string> =
    T extends 
        `${infer RestOne} ${infer RestTwo}` 
        ? Trim<`${RestOne}${RestTwo}`>
        : T extends ` ${infer RestThree} ${infer RestFour}`
           ? Trim<`${RestThree}${RestFour}`>
           : T extends ` ${infer RestFive} ${infer RestSix} `
             ? Trim<`${RestFive}${RestSix}`>
             : T extends `${infer RestSeven} ${infer RestEight} `
               ? Trim<`${RestSeven}${RestEight}`>
               : T;


type TestOne = Trim<" foo"> ; // "foo"
type TestTwo = Trim< " foo "> ; // "foo"
type TestThree = Trim<" foo bar "> ; // "foobar"
type TestThree = Trim<"   foo bar "> ; // "foobar"
type TestFour = Trim<"foo bar ">; // "foobar"

basically, it trims out all space in `Trim<T>`
```

Comment: Actually, this works: ```type Trim<T> = T extends `${infer a} ${infer b}` ? Trim<`${a}${b}`> : T```

Comment: What's the advantage of `Trim<T>` being a type, rather than a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this exmaple:

```js
type Separator = ' ';

type Trim<T extends string, Acc extends string = ''> =
  (T extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Char extends Separator
      ? Trim<Rest, Acc>
      : Trim<Rest, `${Acc}${Char}`>)
    : (T extends ''
      ? Acc
      : never)
  )




type TestOne = Trim<" foo">; // "foo"
type TestTwo = Trim<" foo ">; // "foo"

type TestThree = Trim<" foo bar ">; // "foobar"
type TestThree2 = Trim<"   foo bar ">; // "foobar"
type TestFour = Trim<"foo bar ">; // "foobar"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhYEMBODgHslQLxQOR4G4BYAKFNEigBUkBLAWwB4qoIAPYCAOwBMBnKH2B0uAcwA0UAIIBjGaw7d%20g4bTHY8uAHzZSUKAAoW7TrwEADACQBvNQDMImAMIALZAF8b9x1ABKEIXdzPX0oAH5DV2QFU2U4RBR0JBDQ8Oo6Jn8hSVkZLRTQgC50hkYs4Ekra1zPayikIK0ASgLioxilAVxcAv0I3N6oYq4IADdHFpJ9SdJZshIKaCoA4AB5EY0aUoAiKDs0NG2tAigAelOobf3D8nAllaoAdzRNjMZd68vjs4urg%2025otqA8XEgINAcFsmB8DlAAEbRI4nc6Xa4IpAAhZ3YFCKig8EAJleO1Cn3RX2RvzRyExQOWQgAYmgAK6YSFvP4vclIn6og7ozFAA)

`Trim` - iterates through the whole string. If it finds `Separator` (empty space) it just omits it and concats `Acc` with part of string without separator.

Answer (score 0):

> it trims out all space in `Trim<T>`

That's not exactly what [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) is supposed to do. This sounds more like [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

```
type Whitespace = " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n";

type TrimLeft<Text extends string, Chars extends string | number = Whitespace> =
    Text extends `${Chars}${infer Rest}`
    ? TrimLeft<Rest, Chars>
    : Text;

type TrimRight<Text extends string, Chars extends string | number = Whitespace> =
    Text extends `${infer Rest}${Chars}`
    ? TrimRight<Rest, Chars>
    : Text;

type Trim<Text extends string, Chars extends string | number = Whitespace> =
    TrimRight<TrimLeft<Text, Chars>, Chars>;

type ReplaceAll<Text extends string, Pattern extends string | number, Replacement extends string = ""> =
    Text extends `${infer Start extends string}${Pattern}${infer Rest extends string}`
    ? `${Start}${Replacement}${ReplaceAll<Rest, Pattern, Replacement>}`
    : Text;

type Txt = "    -- foo bar --    ";

type T1 = TrimLeft<Txt>;                     // "-- foo bar --    "
type T1a = TrimLeft<Txt, Whitespace | "-">;  // "foo bar --    "

type T2 = TrimRight<Txt>;                    // "    -- foo bar --"
type T2a = TrimRight<Txt, Whitespace | "-">; // "    -- foo bar"

type T3 = Trim<Txt>;                         // "-- foo bar --"
type T3a = Trim<Txt, Whitespace | "-">;      // "foo bar"

type T4 = ReplaceAll<Txt, Whitespace>;       // "--foobar--"
type T5 = ReplaceAll<Trim<Txt>, Whitespace, "/">; // "--/foo/bar/--"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFgS2BAzmAhgY2gXigIgKgB8CAdYQ0-MgJyvIDt8BuAWAChPRIoAVWggC2AGQgAzYAB4+EAB7Ao85IwAmKKCmCDGAcwA0UAMJx0tDcohqNWnbpJRGAVyEAjCLSh54SVBmwAfF6cUKH8ykoKVupQAAYAJADeJmYoAL5JCIziHlAASqjAabEhYQD8-IKiEtIFWoYp5gGloQBc4QrsXBw80ALCeQi6cNKyCpEqMbZZBsam5hPRNtozDs5uud6IyGhYEEE4LR2KltZxmdm5dUVJjeklHGFQFf1Cg8O1hQ3zKM2PYe0xsAutxwH0qjIIqcpis9N9UosztM9GsXO5PFtfLtAsF-qFXu8RjIqmJJJCFPCmpTfiCemD8hAwAAbPYAQSZTPJJyiSNhswACuhgMhaIxETC7KiNrRDAVmXshFZuZNlpK8Ph8AcjkDxRoEoksjlPABlYBmZVLTR8jKJQXCjyMG2Gq6FXVWuzFI4VfWm802uUs7CKxg3RIBtkcqTXQx2kWMWWMwMQYPAAKevFQQHKWm9fjjdVPAC0hag4gA9mWoK4zFBi09WJxQbw+ABGLyVYSk0YKAIsJ79gcDgD0Q4IdfLlernjrYXwTb6LfQ7deXZkFNg2z8ewc+ELmr7UBHBAnVZrM9Cc+6ub4ACZl1VCd3UwfB6+wkfCGFxxXT9O9-P+BvJc8AJIYiT4dcfB2fxoGoPde0PUdP1Cb9JzMS8AL4ABme9hDXZ830I4ckNQ39a3-Olmyw4COyEfDDCgrdsB3eCX3fJCTynDDKL6AAWdtw2wdlOQg4AGM3bF9jY9ix0LCcp2LS9rwAVgExMIxEiFRICcSsRgwx8CHfdENkocJyHKch0UzggA)